# Why is this SQL not contained in the try Catch

Tags: java, sql, try-catch

Why is the SQL not in the try catch, Problem is I tried using two separate try catches but then the SQL statement could not reference the FileInputStream variable and this was the alternative I came up with but it didn't seem to work

```
try {
    final FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream(ReturnFile);        

    JButton Submit = new JButton ("Insert");
    Submit.setLocation (430, 335);
    Submit.setSize (150, 25);
    newCarFrame.add(Submit);
    Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Connection Con = new DataBaseHandler().GetConnection();
            Statement stmt = Con.createStatement();

            String SQL = "INSERT INTO Cars (`Reg_No`, `Car_Image`, `Make`, `Model`, `Mileage`, `Date_Of_Purchase`, `Price`, `Storage_Location`, `Body_Type`, `Gearbox`, `Age`, `No_Of_Doors`, `Colour`, `Fuel_Type`, `Engine_Size`, `Description`) VALUES ('" + RegNoTextBox.getText() + "', '" + FIS + "', '" + MakeComboBox.getSelectedItem() + "', '" + ModelTextBox.getText() + "', '" + MillageTextBox.getText() + "', '" + DOPField.getText() + "', '" + PriceField.getText() + "', '" + StorageCombo.getSelectedItem() + "', '" + BodyTypesCombo.getSelectedItem() + "', '" + GearBoxValue + "', '" + No_Of_Doors_Combo.getSelectedItem() + "', '" + AgeField.getText() + "', '" + ColourField.getText() + "', '" + PetrolValue + "', '" + EngineSizeField.getText() + "', '" + DescriptionField.getText() + "')";
            System.out.println(SQL);
            //Execute the SQL query
            //TODO Salt the password
            stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);

            Con.close();
            String ShowAllSalesSQL = "SELECT * FROM `Cars`";
            SalesWindow MSW = new SalesWindow (ShowAllSalesSQL);
        }

    });
} catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
    System.out.println("No File");
    e2.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e1) {

}
```

All help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: what error you are getting??

Comment: I am confused. What are you trying to do and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the sql is in the try-catch block.

Comment: @Prashant his `SQLException` is **never** logged nor printed. The OP will never see any exceptions from `SQLException`, if any.

Comment: I suspect that part of your problem is that you're declaring local variables within the `try` range and then trying to reference them outside of that range.  Any variable you want to reference outside of the `try` (or `catch`) range must be declared outside of that range.

Comment: @Prashant It asks me to add a try catch but then when I do the variable doesn't exist outside the try catch

Comment: @HotLicks I can't declare it as a global variable cause then I have to declare it as final but then it says I can't assign as it is a blank variable

Comment: I can't figure out what you think you're doing with `FIS` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you do this `Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener () { ... }` you are actually implementing a `ActionListener` interface inline, as anonymous class. In that `try` block you are only setting the action listener instance to `Submit` button, you are not actually surrounding the code which will be executed when the button is clicked.

Comment: Do u have any advice on how to make allow the SQL string to concatenate the FileInputStream

Comment: You should probably move the whole `try-catch` block inside `actionPerformed()` method, along with `FIS`.

Comment: Ive tried that but then it says that i need another try catch for the input stream and then I have the same problem

Comment: Put both the `FIS` declaration and SQL code inside the same `try` block, and add two `catch` blocks, one for `FileNotFoundException` and another one for `SQLException`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I was being stupid I fixed it as shown below

```
JButton Submit = new JButton ("Insert");
    Submit.setLocation (430, 335);
    Submit.setSize (150, 25);
    newCarFrame.add(Submit);
    Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {

                final FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream(ReturnFile);

                Connection Con = new DataBaseHandler().GetConnection();

                Statement stmt = Con.createStatement();

                String SQL = "INSERT INTO Cars (`Reg_No`, `Car_Image`, `Make`, `Model`, `Mileage`, `Date_Of_Purchase`, `Price`, `Storage_Location`, `Body_Type`, `Gearbox`, `Age`, `No_Of_Doors`, `Colour`, `Fuel_Type`, `Engine_Size`, `Description`) VALUES ('" + RegNoTextBox.getText() + "', '" + FIS + "', '" + MakeComboBox.getSelectedItem() + "', '" + ModelTextBox.getText() + "', '" + MillageTextBox.getText() + "', '" + DOPField.getText() + "', '" + PriceField.getText() + "', '" + StorageCombo.getSelectedItem() + "', '" + BodyTypesCombo.getSelectedItem() + "', '" + GearBoxValue + "', '" + No_Of_Doors_Combo.getSelectedItem() + "', '" + AgeField.getText() + "', '" + ColourField.getText() + "', '" + PetrolValue + "', '" + EngineSizeField.getText() + "', '" + DescriptionField.getText() + "')";
                System.out.println(SQL);
                //Execute the SQL query
                //TODO Salt the password
                stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);

                Con.close();

                String ShowAllSalesSQL = "SELECT * FROM `Cars`";

                SalesWindow MSW = new SalesWindow (ShowAllSalesSQL);

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e3) {
                e3.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just to note: that code is not finished, it is missing some resource cleanup code. It should either use try-with-resources or have a finally clause closing FIS, Con and stmt.